# How can I extract data from JSON if the property name is a random string?

Tags: jquery, json

I am no jquery or javascript expert, and I am using a multiple select plugin (fcbkselect).  Normally I am used to iterating through the post array, but this plugin returns the selected items in a json object such as:

```
{"rand_T6hOMeRa7tKSGTEp2MCWqtRinJyKAEgq":"foobar@gmail.com","rand_DCNxA7hu8LfWkL5T02TbxXN6qwahENtg":"barfoo@yahoo.com"}
```

I am totally clueless as to how I should extract foobar@gmail.com , and barfoo@yahoo.com , etc. reliably every time since he is using random keys.  Any help appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the object in JavaScript:

```
var json_str = '{"rand_T6hOMeRa7tKSGTEp2MCWqtRinJyKAEgq":"foobar@gmail.com","r' +
               'and_DCNxA7hu8LfWkL5T02TbxXN6qwahENtg":"barfoo@yahoo.com"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json_str);
for (var k in obj) {
  console.log('Key: ' + k + ', mail: ' + obj[k]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
 var data = {"rand_T6hOMeRa7tKSGTEp2MCWqtRinJyKAEgq":"foobar@gmail.com","rand_DCNxA7hu8LfWkL5T02TbxXN6qwah    ENtg":"barfoo@yahoo.com"}
 for (a in data) {
    alert(a);
    alert(data[a])
 }
```